# How to store a checkbox object in a list?

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox

I'm struggle with the `CheckBox` in C#

```
 public formPCRBaseline(List<GetBaselineSectionTasks> m_objPCRCheck)
 {
     setDefaults(m_objPCRCheck);
 }

 private void setDefaults(List<GetBaselineSectionTasks> m_objPCRCheck)
 {
     richTextBoxPCRBaseline.BackColor = Color.White;

     foreach (GetBaselineSectionTasks i_objPCRCheck in m_objPCRCheck)
     {
         richTextBoxPCRBaseline.SelectionIndent = 0;
         CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox();
         checkBox.Height = 20;
         checkBox.Width = 20;
         richTextBoxPCRBaseline.Controls.Add(checkBox);
         checkBox.Tag = i_objPCRCheck;
         richTextBoxPCRBaseline.SelectionIndent = 30;
         richTextBoxPCRBaseline.SelectedText = "Section : '" + i_objPCRCheck.taskname;
         richTextBoxPCRBaseline.SelectedText = "\n\n";
     }
}
```

So this code return me a list of object with some checkbox, and I'd like to take the checked checkbox when I clicked on confirm button, so I thought to do something like:

```
private void buttonConfirm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e, out List<GetBaselineSectionTasks> m_objCheckeditem)
{
    int i = 0;
    m_objCheckeditem = new List<GetBaselineSectionTasks>();
    foreach (CheckBox i_objCheck in richTextBoxPCRBaseline.Controls)
    {
        if (i_objCheck.Checked)
        {
            m_objCheckeditem.Add(i_objCheck.Tag);
            MessageBox.Show(i_objCheck.Tag.ToString());
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

And I got this error

> CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'object' to 'MyApplication.GetBaselineSectionTasks'

And it's came from this line: `m_objCheckeditem.Add(i_objCheck.Tag);`

It's the first time that I use the .Tag property so I suggest that it's not working like that.

Any idea of how could I get my checked item and return them?

Comment: what is the problem? could not understand your question quite well.

Comment: It's easy, it's not working

Comment: it is not easy to us since we don't know what is "not working", because we don't viewing your screen. Any error message? Screen capture maybe?

Comment: This is my error message:

CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'object' to 'MyApplication.GetBaselineSectionTasks' 

And it's came from this line:
m_objCheckeditem.Add(i_objCheck.Tag);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the Tag property is used to store arbitrary data, its type is `System.Object`.

You can't add an object of type System.Object to a generic list of `GetBaselineSectionTasks`. So you just need to cast it to the appropriate type.

```
m_objCheckeditem.Add(i_objCheck.Tag as MyApplication.GetBaselineSectionTasks);
```

Comment: Thank, It's worked  but it's return me a blank object
Is there a way to use an output object with a click method? because I get an overload error message

Comment: it is uncommon to use overload for Click event handler. Don't pass the list as argument, just make it a class member.  You can just clear it at the first line of Confirm method so items won't get added repeatedly.